# Rust JWT claim not valid struct field name

Tags: rust, jwt, serde

I'm trying to generate some JWTs using the following https://github.com/Keats/jsonwebtoken crate. Basically, I have

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyTokenClaims {
    foo: String,
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
}
```

Now the problem is that in the JWT the claim `foo` would actually be `example.com/foo`. Is there a way to override the field name in the JWT that is used after encoding it, since I can't create a struct field with that name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `serde` you can [alias](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) the field name:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyTokenClaims {
   #[serde(rename(serialize = "example.com/foo", deserialize = "example.com/foo"))]
    foo: String,
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
}
```

When reading JSON, your code now looks for the field `"example.com/foo": "value"` and serialises the value in rust to `foo: "value"`.

Comment: `#[serde(rename(serialize = "example.com/foo", deserialize = "example.com/foo"))]` can be abbreviated to `#[serde(rename = "example.com/foo")]`.